# Total law of probability problem

Tags: probability

If $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are mutually exclusive and  $A_j = \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(B \mid A_j) = \frac{j}{6}$, for $j=1, 2, 3$, find $P(B)$.

For this problem, I believe I can use the total law of probability, since $A_i$ form a partition (they are mutually exclusive and $P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3) = 1$. Thus I get

$P(B) = P(A_1)P(B \mid A_1)+P(A_2)P(B \mid A_2)+P(A_3)P(B \mid A_3)\\
= \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{6} =\frac{1}{3}$.

Is there any error in my work?

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This Venn diagram should help you:

[image]